# How do I rig toes?

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm working on a rig and would like to know how to rig individual toes. I do not need the whole foot, just the toes. I cannot find anything online about this.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you want to do with the toes, maybe look at some hand rigging tutorials, you could for example give a rotation constraint to your second and third phalanx so that when you rotate the first phalanx it rotates the other ones, but again what are your need?

Comment: Also you can use the Inverse Kinematics constraint to have a better grasp on controlling the bones.

Comment: "how to rig anything with rigify" explains all this stuff and more.  Youtube channel cg dive.

Answer (score 0):

Is is generally hard to give any advice on a rig if the purpose for said rig is unknown.

Generally speaking, you need at least one *Bone* in Blender for every rigid limb in the real world. That means, in order mimic all possible motions of real toes, you'll need at least two bones for the big toe and at least three bones each for all the other toes.

If you're only working on toe animations, it's that easy. If the foot is only part of a bigger model (e.g. a full human body), I would absolutely recommend creating all the other bones that make up said foot. The best way to keep the resulting animation-workflow nice and clean, is to mimic the real body as closely as possible.